# Insert rows to a database table : check if it worked?

Tags: android, database, eclipse

I have in my database two tables : one is full of content and the other just is empty (I have only built the name of the fields and that's it). The whole database is in the assets folder of my application.

I have a method supposed to add a new element to this empty table every time I click on a button.

```
 OnClickListener poi_favoritesbutton_listener = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseAdapter.insertInTable(ID_NAME, ID_CAT1, ID_CAT2, ID_CAT3, ID_CUISINE);
        }
    };
```

Here is the method :

```
    public static long insertInTable(String ID_NAME, String ID_CAT1,
        String ID_CAT2, String ID_CAT3, String ID_CUISINE) {
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    data.put(FAV_NAME, ID_NAME);
    data.put(FAV_CAT1, ID_CAT1);
    data.put(FAV_CAT2, ID_CAT2);
    data.put(FAV_CAT3, ID_CAT3);
    data.put(FAV_CUISINE, ID_CUISINE);
    if (myDatabase == null) {

    }
    return myDatabase.insert("DATABASE_FAVTABLE", null, data);
}
```

I think it should be correct as I have followed what was discussed on SOF related topics but I'd like not just to "think" and be sure instead! I tried using debug mode / DDMC but no way to actually open my database in real time and check for evolution of its content...

Any suggestion ? Thanks !

ps: i'm using a real device to run my test, emulator is just killing my time.

Answer (score 4):

According to [insert() docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29):

> Returns
>       the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

so basically all you need is to check if you did not get said `-1` in return.

Comment: Thanks but I must miss something : where am I supposed to "get -1"? Is there some code to add to display a kind of test? Because I have nothing in my logcat and it's the only thing I use so far.

Comment: I do understand the code, I am just asking: where is the information supposed to be displayed? It may return the row ID of the newly inserted row or -1 or whatever, but obviously not on my screen nor on my logcat which are basically the two things I am using. So again, where is this returned value supposed to be displayed?

Comment: Do whatever you find suitable. Db is telling you if your insert was successful or not. What you do with this information is completelty up to you

Answer (score 0):

> no way to actually open my database in real time and check for evolution of its content

You can pull the database table to the device and see the contents of the table under DDMS tab-> File Explorer

Comment: I can't when I am using a real device, just when I am using the emulator. Moreover, even with the emulator, I can indeed see the file for my database but nothing happens when I click on it.. :s